# How can I select several rows with the Max column value which is grouped by another column?

Tags: group-by, max

I want to get the movie, character_name, and Visits of the 4 rows(*) having the max "Visits" value group by movie.

My table (D) is like this:

```
movie  character_name  Visits
1      Owen Lars      1
1      Obi-Wan Kanobi  2
1      Luke Skywalker  3*
2      Princess Leia  2
2      Luke Skywalker  3*
2      R2-D2          3*
3      Jabba the Hutt  1
3      Han Solo      2
3      Luke Skywalker  4*
```

The best coding I can think of is

```
select * FROM D
group by D.movie
HAVING max(Visits)
```

But i just can't get the right rows >

Can anyone tell me how I should revise it?
thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    D.*
FROM
    D
    INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MOVIE
        ,   MAX(VISITS) AS VISITS
    FROM D
    GROUP BY MOVIE) F ON D.MOVIE = F.MOVIE AND D.VISITS = F.VISITS
```